# Theme setting missing in iPhone Gmail app

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail, dark-mode

I want to turn off dark mode for the gmail app. It turned on yesterday without asking me. I know about the global iPhone dark mode setting and it’s set to dark mode but gmail should have its own setting as well But it’s missing. See attached screenshot. It should be listed under the settings section.

Where is it now?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there doesn’t seem to be a Gmail setting to turn off syncing to the iOS theme (I also looked within the settings of specific mail accounts). This is something Google would need to implement - you can provide this feedback to them from the Gmail app (“Send feedback” is below “Settings” in the side navigation).

As a workaround, you can add “Dark Mode” to your iOS Control Center in System Preferences. This will allow toggling the global theme quickly.

I also noticed that the Outlook iOS app supports overriding the system theme, if you’re looking for an alternative to Gmail.

Comment: Well the interesting thing is that theme setting used to be there but is no longer there. Globally changing to light mode and dark mode after using Gmail is a step I'm not willing to take. I prefer the gmail app so I'll just deal with the default Dark Mode I'm getting from my iOS settings.